# Moq Application.Current.MainWindow in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq, viewmodel

I Have code in my view model as below.

```
private Generate()
{

// Some code here
var window = new CreateWindow
                {
                    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow

                };
}
```

I want to mock the MainWindow object in my unit test. I have tried

```
var app = new Application()
  mock.SetupGet(x => x._mainWindow)
              .Returns(It.IsAny<MainWindow>());
```

but the MainWindow object is always null.

Can anyone provide some useful pointers on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably wrap the `new CreateWindow` line to a Factory pattern.

Create a new WindowFactory class which has a single method and a corresponding interface IWindowFactory.

Then in your `Generate` method call the injected WindowFactory.Create() method.

In you test inject a mocked IWindowFactory which returns a fake Window.

```
public interface IWindowFactory
{
  CreateWindow Create();
}

public class WindowFactory : IWindowFactory
{
  public CreateWindow Create() 
  {
    return new CreateWindow { Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow };
  }
}
```

On your view model add a property

```
public IWindowFactory WindowFactory { get; set; }
```

In your Generate method

```
var window = WindowFactory.Create();
```

Then in your test, when you create your view model, set the WindowFactory to a Mock

Comment: thanks i helped to mock the code well. Both the solutions worked

Answer (score 1):

You can create a IMainWindowProvider interface and MainWindowProvider implementation:

```
public interface IMainWindowProvider
{
    Window GetMainWindow();
}

public class MainWindowProvider : IMainWindowProvider
{
    public Window GetMainWindow() => Application.Current.MainWindow;
}
```

Then in your current code of Create method you can use an instance of this service (that instance can be set up at constructor of your container class that you want to test, and in the application it will be an instance of MainWindowProvider class, e.g. dependency injected):

```
var window = new CreateWindow
{
    Owner = mainWindowProvider.GetMainWindow()
};
```

And in your unit tests you can mock IMainWindowProvider instead of trying to mock Application, and setup the mock to return a dummy new Window instead.

Comment: thanks i helped to mock the code well. Both the solutions worked